# can I specify which test files to run in .coveragerc?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, coverage.py

My file structure is below,

```
Logic
--packageA
----file1
----file2
--packageB
----file3
----file4
--tests
----testfile1
----testfile2
----testfile3
--.coveragerc
```

I'd like to include `packageA` only for tests, and run `testfile1` and `testfile2` to measure the coverage.

`testfile3` is for `packageB`.

So I wrote my `.coveragerc` file,

```
[run]
branch = True
include = /packageA/*
omit = *tests*
```

and, when I run coverage with command `coverage run --rcfile=../.coveragerc -m pytest` in directory `tests`, it tries running `testfile3` as well.

How can I run `testfile1` and `testfile2` with `.coveragerc` configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `[run] command_line` option to set the command line to use when you run `coverage run`.   But coverage isn't trying to be a general runner.  You might want a shell script, a Makefile, or a tox.ini file instead.

Are you typing the `coverage run --rcfile=../.coveragerc -m pytest` command by hand?

Comment: Yes. I found the command what I want, `coverage run --rcfile=../.coveragerc -m pytest testfile1.py testfile2.py` after I posted the question. but still have no idea to specify these test file name `testfile1.py` and `testfile2.py` in `.coveragerc`. Is it not possible?